# Move View on Touch and react on click?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I've created a view which can be dragged around. Here's my source for that:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX + (int)(event.getRawX()-initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int)(event.getRawY()-initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(imageView, params);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

As you might see, by touching the imageview and panning around, the view itself moves. Now my problem is, I want to differenciate between moving the view and actually clicking on the view. I've tried multiple methods shown here on stackoverflow but couldn't find anything which solved my problem.

if the imageview gets clicked on, it should call a method. Otherwise, if it's only touched to move the view, the method should not be called.

Does anybody has an advice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

When your `ACTION_UP` event happens, you want to return `false`, otherwise the `OnClickListener` does not get called because you are telling the system that you have handled that touch event.

You also probably want to get and save the `System.currentTimeMillis()` on your first `ACTION_DOWN` event, then, only return false if the `ACTION_UP` event comes before a threshold time that represents a click.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to check that out

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding @ChrisMcJava's idea and some further tweaks:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;
        private long time;
        private boolean hasMoved = false;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    time = System.nanoTime();
                    hasMoved = false;
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(System.nanoTime() - time < 1000000000  && !hasMoved) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return false;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if(Math.pow(initialTouchX - (int)event.getRawX(), 2) > Math.pow(5, 2) || Math.pow(initialTouchY - (int)event.getRawY(), 2) > Math.pow(5, 2)) {
                        hasMoved = true;
                    }
                    params.x = initialX + (int)(event.getRawX()-initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int)(event.getRawY()-initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(imageView, params);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

As you can see, a click is not only depending on how long it got clicked on, but also if the view was moved or not. I've built in a tolerance of moving 5px and 1second, meaning:
If the button was hold less or equal than 1 second AND the button was not dragged around more than 5px it's a click.

Thanks for the advices

Answer (score 0):

Update the ACTION_UP case as below:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                     if( (Math.abs(initialTouchX - event.getRawX())<5) && (Math.abs(initialTouchY - event.getRawY())<5) )
                     {
                         Log.e(TAG,"It's a click ! ");


                     }else{
                         Log.e(TAG,"you moved the head");

                     }


                     return true;
```